# Reusing <div> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my `<div>` with id = CarSpecs. I want to reuse this piece of code with jQuery's selectors. What I want to achieve is using something such as `$("CarSpecs")` so I won't have a huge HTML file.

Could someone show me how to do this please?

```
    <div id="CarSpecs">
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
                    <h1>Price</h1>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
                    <h1>Body</h1>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
                    <h1>Transmission</h1>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
                    <h1>Engine</h1>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
                    <h1>Fuel</h1>
                </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kNGXf/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="copy"></div>
```

JS:

```
var carspecs = $('#CarSpecs').html();
$('.copy').html(carspecs);
```

or put another way:

```
$('.copy').html($('#CarSpecs').html());
```

[API documentation for .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: @Liondancer So I guess you can delete your duplicate question now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647798/how-to-reuse-html-code-using-jqeury

Answer (score 1):

```
var carspecs = $('#carspecs').html();
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am selecting in the same file. So if I were to call upon this <div> would 

<script> $("#CarSpecs").html(); </script> work?

Comment: if you have a `<div id="newCar"></div>` you can use `$('#newCar').html(carspecs);`

Answer (score 1):

It would look like this in [modest](https://github.com/goalzen/modest):

**main.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <include>CarSpecs</include>
  </head>
  <body>
    <CarSpecs/>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CarSpecs.xml**

```
<div id="CarSpecs">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
            <h1>Price</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
            <h1>Body</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
            <h1>Transmission</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
            <h1>Engine</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
            <h1>Fuel</h1>
        </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want to reuse even more, do this:

**main.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <include>CarSpecs</include>
    <include>CarSpec</include>
  </head>
  <body>
    <CarSpecs/>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CarSpec.xml**

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
    <h1 uses="spec"/>
</div>
```

**CarSpecs.xml**

```
<div>
    <CarSpec spec="Price"/>
    <CarSpec spec="Body"/>
    <CarSpec spec="Transmission"/>
    <CarSpec spec="Engine/>
    <CarSpec spec="Fuel/>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're going to suggest the use of a tool or product you were involved in creating, you need to disclose your involvement in the post... see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior